# VLOOKUP key in table array is a formula

Tags: arrays, vlookup

I am stuck with a VLOOKUP function as the key in the lookup range is a formula, hence the VLOOKUP returns #N/A. I've searching for a solution, but unfortunately was unable to find any similar reports.

In column G I would like to find the corresponding values from column C, with column E as the lookup value. But the key in the lookup range is a function (column A) what I use to get the numbers only from the value in columng B.
[image]

If this could be somehow done by directly looking up by the numbers in column B that would be even better.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the formula in column A returning a string and your search argument is a number.
Try making your value in col A numeric, i.e. surrounding the formula with INT

```
=INT(RIGHT(blah, blah...)..)
```